# Call function on another contract failed

Tags: token, ethereum, solidity, erc20

I'm studying solidity.

TT3 token generation on test net is no problem, but TT3Token_Test failed.
(TT3Token and TT3Token_Test have been deployed to the same wallet address)

https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x4099019ecc47640dc7d3ceb3de3d50759f4e5ebc6d730410cda992c97d78ea10

I do not know why not.

(I deployed it to ropsten using remix)

---

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.23;

import "./StandardToken.sol"; // openzeppelin

contract TT3Token is StandardToken {
    string public constant name = "TT3Token";
    string public constant symbol = "TT3";
    uint8 public constant decimals = 18;
    uint256 public constant INITIAL_SUPPLY = 10000 * (10 ** uint256(decimals));

    constructor() public {
        totalSupply_ = INITIAL_SUPPLY;
        balances[msg.sender] = INITIAL_SUPPLY;
        emit Transfer(0x0, msg.sender, INITIAL_SUPPLY);
    }

    function sendTest(address _to, uint256 _value) public {
        transfer(_to, _value);
    }
}

contract TT3Token_Test {
    constructor() public {
        address r = 0xEcA254594c5bBCCEBc321e9252cc886cE37Be914;

        TT3Token token = TT3Token(msg.sender);
        token.sendTest(r, 99 * (10 ** uint256(18)));
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "failed"?

Comment: @Venantius  A transaction error occurs. https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x4099019ecc47640dc7d3ceb3de3d50759f4e5ebc6d730410cda992c97d78ea10

Answer (score 1):

`TT3Token token = TT3Token(msg.sender)` doesn't make sense unless it's the `TT3Token` contract itself that is creating a new `TT3Token_Test` deployment (which is not shown in your code). `msg.sender` is the address from which the transaction was initiated from (an EOA account). It should be the address of your deployed `TT3Token` contract.

Also, the tokens are owned by the address that deployed the `TT3Token` contract. You need to transfer tokens from that same account to the `TT3Token_Test` address in order for the call to `sendTest` to succeed.

Comment: TT3Token and TT3Token_Test have been deployed to the same wallet address.

Comment: Does the owner of the TT3 token fail to call sendTest from TT3Token_Test?

Comment: Right now, the code, as posted, is failing because there is no `sendTest` method on the address represented by `msg.sender`. That is the address of your wallet, not the address of the deployed contract.